# How to iterate over result of Future List in Scala?

Tags: scala, akka, concurrent.futures

I am new to Scala and was trying my hands on with `akka`. I am trying to access data from MongoDB in Scala and want to convert it into JSON and XML format.
This code attached below is using path ***/getJson*** and calling getJson() function to get data in a form of future.

```scala
get {
  concat(
    path("getJson"){
      val f = Patterns.ask(actor1,getJson(),10.seconds)
      val res  = Await.result(f,10.seconds)
      val result = res.toString
      complete(res.toString)
    }
}
```

The getJson() method is as follows:

```
def getJson()= {
  val future = collection.find().toFuture()
  future
}
```

I have a Greeting Case class in file `Greeting.scala`:

```
case class Greeting(msg:String,name:String)
```

And MyJsonProtocol.scala file for Marshelling of scala object to JSON format as follows:

```
trait MyJsonProtocol extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val templateFormat = jsonFormat2(Greeting)
}
```

I am getting output of **`complete(res.toString)`** in Postman as :

```scala
Future(Success(List(
  Iterable(
    (_id,BsonObjectId{value=5fc73944986ced2b9c2527c4}), 
    (msg,BsonString{value='Hiiiiii'}), 
    (name,BsonString{value='Ruchirrrr'})
  ),
  Iterable(
    (_id,BsonObjectId{value=5fc73c35050ec6430ec4b211}),
    (msg,BsonString{value='Holaaa Amigo'}), 
    (name,BsonString{value='Pablo'})), 
  Iterable(
    (_id,BsonObjectId{value=5fc8c224e529b228916da59d}), 
    (msg,BsonString{value='Demo'}), 
    (name,BsonString{value='RuchirD'}))
)))
```

Can someone please tell me how to iterate over this output and to display it in JSON format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Scala, its very important to know your way around types. First step toweards this is at least knowing the types of your variables and values.

If you look at this method,

```scala
def getJson() = {
  val future = collection.find().toFuture()
  future
}
```

Is lacks the type type information at all levels, which is a really bad practice.

I am assuming that you are using mongo-scala-driver. And your `collection` is actually a `MongoCollection[Document]`.

Which means that the output of `collection.find()` should be a `FindOberservable[Document]`, hence `collection.find().toFuture()` should be a `Future[Seq[Document]]`. So, your `getJson` method should be written as,

```scala
def getJson(): Future[Seq[Document]] =
  collection.find().toFuture()
```

Now, this means that you are passing a `Future[Seq[Document]]` to your `actor1`, which is again a bad practice. You should never send any kind of `Future` values among actors. It looks like your `actor1` does nothing but sends the same message back. Why does this `actor1` even required when it does nothing ?

Which means your `f` is a `Future[Future[Seq[Document]]]`. Then you are using `Await.result` to get the result of this future `f`. Which is again an anti-pattern, since `Await` blocks your thread.

Now, your `res` is a `Future[Seq[Document]]`. And you are converting it to a `String` and sending that string back with `complete`.

Your `JsonProtocol` is not working because you are not even passing it any `Greeting's`.

You have to do the following,

1. Read raw Bson objects from mongo.
2. convert raw Bson objects to your `Gretting` objects.
3. comlete your result with these `Gretting` objects. The JsonProtocol should take case of converting these `Greeting` objects to `Json`.

The easist way to do all this is by using the mongo driver's `CodecRegistreis`.

```
case class Greeting(msg:String, name:String)
```

Now, your `MongoDAL` object will look like following (it might be missing some imports, fill any missing imports as you did in your own code).

```scala
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.Macros
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries
import org.mongodb.scala.{MongoClient, MongoCollection, MongoDatabase}

object MongoDAL {

  val greetingCodecProvider = Macros.createCodecProvider[Greeting]()

  val codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
    CodecRegistries.fromProviders(greetingCodecProvider),
    DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY
  )

  val mongoClient: MongoClient = ... // however you are connecting to mongo and creating a mongo client

  val mongoDatabase: MongoDatabase = 
    mongoClient
      .getDatabase("database_name")
      .withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)

  val greetingCollection: MongoCollection[Greeting] =
    mongoDatabase.getCollection[Greeting]("greeting_collection_name")

  def fetchAllGreetings(): Future[Seq[Greeting]] =
    greetingCollection.find().toFuture()

}
```

Now, your route can be defined as

```scala
get {
  concat(
    path("getJson") {
      val greetingSeqFuture: Future[Seq[Greeting]] = MongoDAL.fetchAllGreetings()

      // I don't see any need for that actor thing,
      // but if you really need to do that, then you can
      // do that by using flatMap to chain future computations.
      val actorResponseFuture: Future[Seq[Greeting]] = 
        greetingSeqFuture
          .flatMap(greetingSeq => Patterns.ask(actor1, greetingSeq, 10.seconds))

      // complete can handle futures just fine
      // it will wait for futre completion
      // then convert the seq of Greetings to Json using your JsonProtocol
      complete(actorResponseFuture)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks It worked for me. Could you also suggest like here we converted into JSON, how can I convert Bson objects to Greetings object and then Greetings object into XML format?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't call `toString` in `complete(res.toString)`.

As it said in [AkkaHTTP json support guide](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html) if you set everything right, your case class will be converted to json automatically.

But as I see in the output, your `res` is not an object of a `Greeting` type. Looks like it is somehow related to the `Greeting` and has the same structure. Seems to be a raw output of the MongoDB request. If it is a correct assumption, you should convert the raw output from MongoDB to your `Greeting` case class.
I guess it could be done in `getJson()`  after `collection.find()`.